# What will be the reason for getting -1 as a return value for the getopt?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I'm using getopt function as follows,

```
char c;
void function(int len,char **data_buff)
{
    while ((c = getopt(len, data_buff,
                         "M:i:h:b:p:s:a:m:c:H:P:f:x:y:l:u:V:D:U:W:O:E:F:R:N:n:B")) != EOF)
      {
        printf("c==>%c\n", c);
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'M': /** InputMode **/
          printf("in case M");
          break;
        case 'i': / serial input device /
           printf("in case i");
          break;
        case 'B': / bind to incoming UDP stream /
           printf("in case B");
          break;
        case 'V': / Sisnet data server version number /
           printf("in case V");
          break;
        case 'b': / serial input baud rate /
           printf("in case b");
          break;
        case 'a': / Destination caster address /
           printf("in case a");
          break;
        case 'p': / Destination caster port /
           printf("in case p");
          break;
        case 'm': / Destination caster mountpoint for stream upload /
           printf("in case m");
          break;
        case 's': / File name for input data simulation from file /
          printf("in case s");
          break;
        case 'f': / name of an initialization file /
           printf("in case f");
          break;
        case 'x': / user ID to access incoming stream /
           printf("in case x");
          break;
        case 'y': / password to access incoming stream /
          printf("in case y");
          break;
        case 'u': / Sisnet data server user ID /
           printf("in case u");
          break;
        case 'l': / Sisnet data server password /
           printf("in case l");
          break;
        case 'c': / DestinationCaster password for stream upload to mountpoint /
           printf("in case c");
          break;
        case 'H': /* Input host address*/
           printf("in case H");
          break;
        case 'P': / Input port /
          printf("in case P");
          break;
        case 'D': / Source caster mountpoint for stream input /
           printf("in case D");
          break;
        case 'U': / Source caster user ID for input stream access /
          printf("in case U");
          break;
        case 'W': / Source caster password for input stream access /
           printf("in case W]");
          break;
        case 'E': / Proxy Server /
           printf("in case E");
          break;
        case 'F': / Proxy port /
           printf("in case F");
          break;
        case 'R': / maximum delay between reconnect attempts in seconds /
           printf("in case R");
          break;
        case 'O': / OutputMode /
           printf("in case O");
          break;
        case 'n': / Destination caster user ID for stream upload to mountpoint /
           printf("in case n");
          break;
        case 'N': / Ntrip-STR, optional for Ntrip Version 2.0 /
          printf("in case N");
          break;
        case 'h': / print help screen /
         printf("in case h");
          break;
        case '?':
           printf("in case ?");
          break;
        default:
          printf("in case default");
          break;
        }
      }
}
```

I'm passing array of char pointer(as mentioned below) as an argument for the function where the above while is running.

```
char *ntrip_buff1[19];

ntrip_buff1[0] = "./ntripserver";
    ntrip_buff1[1] = "-M";
    ntrip_buff1[2] = "1";
    ntrip_buff1[3] = "-i";
    ntrip_buff1[4] = "/dev/ttymxc5";
    ntrip_buff1[5] = "-b";
    ntrip_buff1[6] = "115200";
    ntrip_buff1[7] = "-O";
    ntrip_buff1[8] = "1";
    ntrip_buff1[9] = "-a";
    ntrip_buff1[10] = "abc.com";
    ntrip_buff1[11] = "-p";
    ntrip_buff1[12] = "2101";
    ntrip_buff1[13] = "-m";
    ntrip_buff1[14] = "Mount2";
    ntrip_buff1[15] = "-n";
    ntrip_buff1[16] = "BroadlySoughtCub";
    ntrip_buff1[17] = "-c";
    ntrip_buff1[18] = "sauhduhasd";
```

So I observed that initially it will work fine but, whenever I change the above buffer and pass it to the function as an argument then in that case it is returning -1 always.
For example-

```
ntrip_buff1[18] = "sauhduhasd";
```

changed to

```
ntrip_buff1[18] = "abcd";
```

So what will be the reason for getting -1 as the return value for the **getopt** function?

Comment: By default, `getopt()` permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans so that, eventually, all the nonoptions are at the end.

Comment: Note that POSIX [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) returns `-1` when there are no more options to process (and not `EOF`, even though the two are usually the same value).  That's so that `getopt()` can be declared in `<unistd.h>` without requiring `<stdio.h>` to be included.  This detail is mentioned in the 'rationale' section of the POSIX specification.

Comment: Your array of arguments needs to end with a null pointer.  You need to increase the size of the array by 1 — or, better, use an initializer instead of umpteen assignments, and the last item in the initializer list should be a null pointer.

Comment: is there any other function which I can use instead of this getopt

Comment: You can always use `getopt_long()` instead.

Comment: @OmkarDixit: you can roll your own if you want, but what's the problem.  (I can think of several, but I wouldn't readily replace `getopt()` with my own code.). The function is designed for parsing the arguments provided to `main()`.  It works fine when the arguments conform to what is provided to `main()` — the value in `argv[0]` is the program name and the value in `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.  One of the issues is 'reusing' `getopt()` in a single run of the program, with a different `argv` list.  Resetting it to reanalyze a new argument list is tricky (because not formally documented).

Comment: Also, `getopt()` returns an `int` — why are you storing its return value in a `char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use `getopt()` to analyze more than one set of arguments in a single run, you have to work out how your particular version of `getopt()` allows you to do that — if, indeed, it does allow you to do it.

On macOS Big Sur 11.7.1, for example, the manual page documents:

> ```
> extern int optreset;
> ```
>
> …
>
> In order to use `getopt()` to evaluate multiple sets of arguments, or to evaluate a single set of arguments multiple times, the variable `optreset` must be set to 1 before the second and each additional set of calls to `getopt()`, and the variable `optind` must be initialized *[…to 1]*.

Adapting your code a bit and creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
— the same idea by a different name), I produced the following code.  Note that it has a null pointer at the end of the argument list.

```
/* SO 7447-0255 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void function(int len, char **data_buff)
{
    int c;
    /* Dropped colon after h in option list */
    while ((c = getopt(len, data_buff,
                       "M:i:hb:p:s:a:m:c:H:P:f:x:y:l:u:V:D:U:W:O:E:F:R:N:n:B")) != -1)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'M': /** InputMode **/
            printf("in case M [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'i':
            /* serial input device */
            printf("in case i [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'B':
            /* bind to incoming UDP stream */
            printf("in case B\n");
            break;
        case 'V':
            /* Sisnet data server version number */
            printf("in case V [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            /* serial input baud rate */
            printf("in case b [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'a':
            /* Destination caster address */
            printf("in case a [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'p':
            /* Destination caster port */
            printf("in case p [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'm':
            /* Destination caster mountpoint for stream upload */
            printf("in case m [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 's':
            /* File name for input data simulation from file */
            printf("in case s [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'f':
            /* name of an initialization file */
            printf("in case f [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'x':
            /* user ID to access incoming stream */
            printf("in case x [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'y':
            /* password to access incoming stream */
            printf("in case y [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'u':
            /* Sisnet data server user ID */
            printf("in case u [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'l':
            /* Sisnet data server password */
            printf("in case l [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'c':
            /* DestinationCaster password for stream upload to mountpoint */
            printf("in case c [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'H': /* Input host address*/
            printf("in case H [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'P':
            /* Input port */
            printf("in case P [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'D':
            /* Source caster mountpoint for stream input */
            printf("in case D [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'U':
            /* Source caster user ID for input stream access */
            printf("in case U [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'W':
            /* Source caster password for input stream access */
            printf("in case W] [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'E':
            /* Proxy Server */
            printf("in case E [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'F':
            /* Proxy port */
            printf("in case F [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'R':
            /* maximum delay between reconnect attempts in seconds */
            printf("in case R [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'O':
            /* OutputMode */
            printf("in case O [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            /* Destination caster user ID for stream upload to mountpoint */
            printf("in case n [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'N':
            /* Ntrip - STR, optional for Ntrip Version 2.0 */
            printf("in case N [%s]\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'h':
            /* print help screen */
            printf("in case h\n");
            break;
        case '?':
            printf("in case ?\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("in case default (option %c)\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = optind; i < len; i++)
        printf("Non-option argument %d: [%s]\n", i, data_buff[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ntrip[] =
    {
        [0] = "./ntripserver",
        [1] = "-M",
        [2] = "1",
        [3] = "-i",
        [4] = "/dev/ttymxc5",
        [5] = "-b",
        [6] = "115200",
        [7] = "-O",
        [8] = "1",
        [9] = "-a",
        [10] = "abc.com",
        [11] = "-p",
        [12] = "2101",
        [13] = "-m",
        [14] = "Mount2",
        [15] = "-n",
        [16] = "BroadlySoughtCub",
        [17] = "-c",
        [18] = "sauhduhasd",
        [19] = NULL,
    };
    enum { NUM_NTRIP = sizeof(ntrip) / sizeof(ntrip[0]) };

    printf("Pass 1:\n");
    function(NUM_NTRIP-1, ntrip);

    printf("Pass 2:\n");
    function(NUM_NTRIP-1, ntrip);

    /* macOS / *BSD getopt() */
    optreset = 1;  // Delete this line with GNU getopt
    optind = 1;
    printf("Pass 3:\n");
    function(NUM_NTRIP-1, ntrip);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produced:

```
Pass 1:
in case M [1]
in case i [/dev/ttymxc5]
in case b [115200]
in case O [1]
in case a [abc.com]
in case p [2101]
in case m [Mount2]
in case n [BroadlySoughtCub]
in case c [sauhduhasd]
Pass 2:
Pass 3:
in case M [1]
in case i [/dev/ttymxc5]
in case b [115200]
in case O [1]
in case a [abc.com]
in case p [2101]
in case m [Mount2]
in case n [BroadlySoughtCub]
in case c [sauhduhasd]
```

Note that Phase 2 without any reset didn't produce any results.

The GNU [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) manual doesn't document how to reset the argument handling (and doesn't provide the explicit `optreset` mechanism), but empirically, just resetting `optind = 1;` works OK.  The only thing to be leery of is if you stop the first cycle of parsing part way through the processing of `argv[1]` and `argv[1]` is something like `-abc` (three single-letter options ganged up).  You should be OK if you process to the end of the arguments on each cycle.